# Dynamically Render Database Records in Rails using Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping to be able to render a tab for each of my project tasks. Currently, the only tab active is the first one (which I'm not terribly surprised since I'm including my index == 0 condition on the tabpanel div, but in my tinkering I haven't been able to select the proper tab) How can I change this to render the proper project task when selected? Is there an effective way to render this kind of content without using AJAX?

```
 <div class='well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2'>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
    <% @project.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
        <li role="presentation" class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if index == 0 %>">
          <a href="#<% task.title %>" aria-controls="<% task.title.downcase %>"
             role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%= task.title %></a>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <% @project.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in <%= 'active' if index == 0 %>" id="<%= task.title.downcase %>">
        <p><%= task.title %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" %>
</div>
```

[In this case, the tab body should read 'Support'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlEHW.png)

Comment: What's not working?  It looks like the general form of your code is correct.

Comment: @MichaelChaney Added an image to better illustrate the issue; my <%= 'active' if index == 0 %> condition ensures that the first tab always renders. If I remove the condition, every task's title will display in the view. What I'm not sure about is how to ensure the selected tab is the only one rendering the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would like to suggest using id with index number as shown in code below I merge the id with rails code **<%=#{index}%>**
- below is some code sample that I created based your code above

  ```
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <% @project.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
                  <% if index == 0 %>
                      <li class="active"><a href="#tab<%=#{index}%>" data-toggle="tab"><p><%= task.title %></p></a></li>                       
                  <% else %>
                      <li><a href="#tab<%=#{index}%>" data-toggle="tab"><%= task.title %></a></li>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>                    
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="tab-content">
                      <% @project.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
                          <% if index == 0 %>
                              <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab<%=#{index}%>">
                                  <p><%= task.title %></p>
                              </div>                            
                          <% else %>
                              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab<%=#{index}%>">
                                  <p><%= task.title %></p>
                              </div>
                          <% end %>
                      <% end %>
              </div>
      </div>
  ```